# Create bool column based on bool and float condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create. `bool` column in a dataframe with the following logic:

`df.a` = `bool` (0 or 1)

`df.start` = `float`

`df.stop` = `float`

if `df.a` == 1 and if `df.start.shift(1) - df.stop >= 5`, return 1, else return 0

I am currently using this code:

```
    df['newColumn'] = (df['a'] & (df['start'].shift(1) - df['stop']) >= 5)
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'
```

Here is a sample df:

```
a    start   stop
0      .5    1.2
1     1.5    2.2 
1     2.3    2.9
0     8.1    8.8
0     17.9    18.1
```

which should be:

```
a    start   stop.  newColumn
0      .5    1.2     0
1     1.5    2.2     0
1     2.3    2.9     1
0     8.1    8.8     0
0     17.9    18.1    0
```

Comment: `((df['a']) & ((df['start'].shift(1) - df['stop']) >= 5))`?

Comment: @Cyttorak I get the same error as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should adding the `()` for each condition when chain with & or |

```
df['newColumn'] = df['a'].astype(bool) & ((df['start'].shift(1) - df['stop']) >= 5)
```